# Json_decode return NULL with a valid JSON after receiving the data with curl

Tags: php, json, curl

Hi there i'm triyng to decode my recived JSON with `json_decode()` but return me a NULL everytime.

```
     foreach ($_data->response as $item){
    $test[$item->plugin] = $item->new_version;
}
$compteur = 0;
$compteur2 = 0;
$values = array();
foreach ($apl as $p){
    if ($_data != null){
            if(isset($test[$p])) {

                $values[$compteur] = array(
                    'id' => $compteur,
                    'plugin_name' => $plugins[$p]["Name"],
                    'plugin_version' => $plugins[$p]["Version"],
                    'plugin_up_to_date' => $test[$p],
                );

            }
            else{

                $values[$compteur] = array(
                    'id' => $compteur,
                    'plugin_name' => $plugins[$p]["Name"],
                    'plugin_version' => $plugins[$p]["Version"],
                    'plugin_up_to_date' => '0'
                );

            }

    }
    else{
        array_push($values, array(
            'id' => $compteur,
            'plugin_name' => $plugins[$p]["Name"],
            'plugin_version' => $plugins[$p]["Version"],
            'plugin_up_to_date' => '0'
        ));
        $compteur2++;
    }
    $compteur++;

}
$compteur = 0;
$compteur2 = 0;

array_push($values, array(
    'Framework' => "WordPress",
    'Version' => $wp_version,
));

$values = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $values)));
$values = array_values($values);


/* Codage de la clé de cryptage sous 16 Bytes */
$enc = MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128;
$key = "mercijackymichel";
$mode = MCRYPT_MODE_CBC;
$text = "123";
$ivSize = 16;
$iv = str_repeat("\0", $ivSize); 

/*returning the json*/ 

return  $crypt = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt($enc, $key, json_encode($values), $mode, $iv));
```

This is my code that make my JSON

The JSON look like this :

```
    [{"id":0,"plugin_name":"Akeeba Backup for WordPress","plugin_version":"1.9.0","plugin_up_to_date":"0"},{"id":1,"plugin_name":"Contact Form 7","plugin_version":"4.4.2","plugin_up_to_date":"0"},{"id":2,"plugin_name":"Cornerstone","plugin_version":"1.2.4","plugin_up_to_date":"1.3.0"},{"id":3,"plugin_name":"Duplicate Page","plugin_version":"1.4","plugin_up_to_date":"0"},{"id":4,"plugin_name":"Slider Revolution","plugin_version":"5.2.5.3","plugin_up_to_date":"5.2.6"},{"id":5,"plugin_name":"WordPress Importer","plugin_version":"0.6.1","plugin_up_to_date":"0"},{"id":6,"plugin_name":"Yoast SEO","plugin_version":"3.4","plugin_up_to_date":"3.4.1"},{"id":7,"plugin_name":"WP Migrate DB","plugin_version":"0.8","plugin_up_to_date":"0"},{"id":8,"plugin_name":"X – Google Analytics","plugin_version":"1.0.0","plugin_up_to_date":"0"},{"Framework":"WordPress","Version":"4.5.3"}]
```

And there is the code that call my php script :

```
    $curlSession = curl_init();

    echo '<br>'.$url.'<br><br>';

    $ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2';
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, $url.'backup/getModul.php');
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $ua);

     $result =base64_decode( curl_exec($curlSession));

    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curlSession, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if ($httpCode == 401){
        echo 'Problème de connexion check .htacces';
    }else{


        $decrypt =  mcrypt_decrypt($enc, $key, $result, $mode, $iv);
        var_dump($decrypt);
        var_dump(json_decode($decrypt));
        var_dump(json_last_error());
        var_dump(json_last_error_msg());

    }

    curl_close($curlSession);
```

But this return me a NULL everytime, i alredy try to call `stripslashes()` on it, to rencode it in UTF-8 but nothing seems to work

```
    Control character error, possibly incorrectly encoded
```

This is the error i get by calling `json_last_error()`

If you have any idea .. Would be great !

Comment: Probably the decryption is wrong, what does `var_dump($decrypt);` actually show

Comment: I test without my encryption and doesn't work aswell 
It show exactly the same JSON that i made with my script

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Z9NGDyrn this is what var_dump($decrypt) show

Comment: It works for me. Your exact text worked. Try : var_dump(json_decode(strval($decrypt)));

Comment: Same error :/ the weird thing is i try https://fr.functions-online.com/json_decode.html this website with my JSON and it work well .. but not in my code, seems like there is an encoding problème or something like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encryption/decryption algorithm is adding padding to conform to the block-size. You should remove null-characters from the end, for example:

```
rtrim($decrypted, "\0");
```